# Inserting characters into a string

Tags: c, string

I want to add `""` to `{"status":true}` so that the string looks like `"{"status":"true"}"`. How can I insert characters to a string at specific locations?

I tried `strncat()`, but wasn't able to get the desired result. I read that you need to create your own function for that. Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you have in your string and what you want in it.  Enclose the characters in the string in back-ticks in the question (like the mention of `strncat()` is now enclosed in back-ticks).   It is not clear (to me) what you have and what you want.

Comment: It is very hard to use `strncat()` accurately.  The length specified is the maximum number of characters that can be appended to the given string.  That means you must know how long the data already in the string is as well as how much space there is in total, but if you know that, you could provide a pointer to the end of the existing string, saving `strncat()` from rescanning the string.  Oh well...

Comment: Consider this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38797570/2410359)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you will need to write your own function for that.

Note that a string in C is a `char[]`, i.e. an array of characters, and is of fixed size.

What you can do is, create a new string that serves as the result, copy the first part of the subject string into it, append the string that goes in the middle, and append the second half of the subject string.

The code goes something like,

```
// inserts into subject[] at position pos
void append(char subject[], const char insert[], int pos) {
    char buf[100] = {}; // 100 so that it's big enough. fill with zeros
    // or you could use malloc() to allocate sufficient space
    // e.g. char *buf = (char*)malloc(strlen(subject) + strlen(insert) + 2);
    // to fill with zeros: memset(buf, 0, 100);

    strncpy(buf, subject, pos); // copy at most first pos characters
    int len = strlen(buf);
    strcpy(buf+len, insert); // copy all of insert[] at the end
    len += strlen(insert);  // increase the length by length of insert[]
    strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos); // copy the rest

    strcpy(subject, buf);   // copy it back to subject
    // Note that subject[] must be big enough, or else segfault.
    // deallocate buf[] here, if used malloc()
    // e.g. free(buf);
}
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/Z2bL5vPx)

Comment: That looks good, except that I would calculate the size of the target array (VLA), rather than hard-coding to 100.  Also, empty braces (`{}`) like that are not valid C.

Comment: In C, a _string_ is a sequence of characters up to and including a final null character.  It need not be an array nor of fixed array size.

Comment: If `pos > strlen(subject)`, then `strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos);` is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprintf()`.

```
const char *source = "{\"status\":\"true\"}";

/* find length of the source string */
int source_len = strlen(source);

/* find length of the new string */
int result_len = source_len + 2; /* 2 quotation marks */

/* allocate memory for the new string (including null-terminator) */
char *result = malloc((result_len + 1) * sizeof(char));

/* write and verify the string */
if (sprintf(result, "\"%s\"", source) != result_len) { /* handle error */ }

/* result == "\"{\"status\":\"true\"}\"" */
```

Comment: "allocate memory for the new string" - Don't forget to `free()`.

Comment: Also, you didn't insert the quotes as the OP specifies; you only added the outer quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted an implementation of strinsert and pasted it below. It compiles and the tests pass with VS2010.

The function takes a pointer to the destination buffer, the destination buffer size, string to insert, and the location to insert the string. The function returns -1 in case of error otherwise it returns the size of the destination buffer. If the destination buffer is too small to accommodate the inserted string, it resizes the buffer using realloc and returns the new buffer size.

I used memmove instead of strncpy as I believe strncpy is undefined when the source and destination overlap. This can be possible if the inserted string is smaller than the amount of memory that is moved.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <assert.h>

int strinsert(char **dest, size_t destsize, char *ins, size_t location)
{
    size_t origsize = 0;
    size_t resize = 0;
    size_t inssize = 0;

    if (!dest || !ins)
        return -1;  // invalid parameter

    if (strlen(ins) == 0)
        return -1; // invalid parameter

    origsize = strlen(*dest);
    inssize = strlen(ins);
    resize = strlen(*dest) + inssize + 1; // 1 for the null terminator

    if (location > origsize)
        return -1; // invalid location, out of original string

    // resize string to accommodate inserted string if necessary
    if (destsize < resize) 
        *dest = (char*)realloc(*dest, resize);

    // move string to make room for insertion
    memmove(&(*dest)[location+inssize], &(*dest)[location], origsize - location);
    (*dest)[origsize + inssize] = '\0'; // null terminate string

    // insert string
    memcpy(&(*dest)[location], ins, inssize);

    return max(destsize, resize); // return buffer size
}

void check(int retVal)
{
    if (retVal < 0)
    {
        assert(!"error code returned!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

#define STARTSTRING "Hello world!"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // initialize str
    int bufsize = strlen(STARTSTRING) + 1 + 10; // added 1 for null terminator and 10 to test resize on demand
    int prevbufsize = 0;
    char *str = (char*)malloc(bufsize);
    strncpy_s(str, bufsize, STARTSTRING, strlen(STARTSTRING));
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    // test inserting in the middle
    prevbufsize = bufsize;
    bufsize = strinsert(&str, bufsize, "awesome ", 6);
    assert(bufsize == prevbufsize); // this should not resize the buffer as it has room for 10 more bytes 
    check(bufsize);
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    // test inserting at front
    prevbufsize = bufsize;
    bufsize = strinsert(&str, bufsize, "John says ", 0);
    assert(bufsize > prevbufsize); 
    check(bufsize);
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    // test inserting char in the middle
    prevbufsize = bufsize;
    bufsize = strinsert(&str, bufsize, "\"", 10);
    assert(bufsize > prevbufsize); 
    check(bufsize);
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    // test inserting char at end
    prevbufsize = bufsize;
    bufsize = strinsert(&str, bufsize, "\"", strlen(str));
    assert(bufsize > prevbufsize); 
    check(bufsize);
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
str = Hello world!
str = Hello awesome world!
str = John says Hello awesome world!
str = John says "Hello awesome world!
str = John says "Hello awesome world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>


//{"status":true}\0_ _  
//{"status": true " } \0  

/*
 * parses the string, reallocates and shifts chars as needed, not generic though
 */

int
insertQuotes(char ** original, int sizeOriginal)
{
    int i = 0;
    char * start = NULL;
    char * temp = NULL;
    long lenLeft = 0;

    int newSize = sizeOriginal + 2;

    if(*original == NULL)
        return -1; 

    *original = realloc(*original, newSize);
    if (*original) {
        start = strstr(*original, ":");
        temp = *original + newSize - 1;
        *temp = '\0';
        temp--;
        *temp = '}';
        temp--;
        *temp = '"';
        temp--;

        while (temp > start + 1) {
            *(temp) = *(temp - 1);
            temp--;
        }
        *temp = '"'; 
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char * original = NULL;
    int retval = 0;

    original = (char *)malloc(sizeof("{\"status\":true}"));
    if (!original) return 1;    

    strncpy(original, "{\"status\":true}", sizeof("{\"status\":true}"));

    retval = insertQuotes(&original, sizeof("{\"status\":true}"));
    if (!retval) {
    printf("\nnew original is [%s]", original);
   }
   free(original);
   return 0;
}
```