# Stack Smashing Detected in C

Tags: c

I have a loop running to add spaces between some special characters (&,|,<,>). The following code successfully adds spaces before and after a special character:

```
    char keys[] = "<>&|";
    int i = strcspn (input,keys); 
    appenda(input, " " , i);
    appenda(input, " " , i+2);
```

The above code converts input "asdf&asdf" to "asdf & asdf".

However, my goal is to do that for every special character in the entire input even with multiple special characters (like "asdf&asdf&asdf"). So I made a while loop:

```
    char keys[] = "<>&|";
    int i = strcspn (input,keys);
    while(i < strlen(input)){
        appenda(input, " " , i);
        appenda(input, " " , i+2);
        i = strcspn (input,keys);
    }
```

Yet, when I run my code now, it returns with "********* stack smashing detected *********"

Any Ideas on what this means and how to get around it?

**EDIT**
Appenda inserts a string into another string at a designated point. it takes in 3 arguments: 1st is a string which i insert into, 2nd is a string which i want to insert and 3rd is the index. so appenda(ABCD, X, 2) returns AXBCD

Comment: Since we have no idea what "appenda" is or what it does, what "input" is or where it comes from, it's going to be pretty hard for us to help you.

Comment: My ESP says that your `input` variable doesn't point to enough space to hold all the extra spaces you are adding and so you are accessing it out of bounds inside `appenda`.

Comment: "Any Ideas on what this means" - the potential of a Google search diverges towards infinity...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Valid point. Appenda inserts a string into another string at a designated point. it takes in 3 arguments: 1st is a string which i insert into, 2nd is a string which i want to insert and 3rd is the index. so appenda(ABCD, X, 2) returns AXBCD

Comment: Please post the implementation of `appenda`, it is likely that the bug is in there. Also post the declaration of `input`.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry appenda was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459259/inserting-characters-into-a-string (its called append - the accepted answer). I don't see how the problem can be in appenda since the code works without the loop. with the loop however, it crashes on the same input (even with only 1 special character)

Comment: I suspect `input`, show the declaration of `input`.

Comment: @rjayavrp char input[200]; fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're always calling `strcspn` on the same `input`, and you're never actually removing the characters that it's finding, so it is always finding the same one.

For example, if your string is

```
asdf&asdf&asdf
```

The first call to

```
int i = strcspn (input,keys)
```

Returns `i = 3` since the `&` is in position 4. Then you insert the spaces, which works fine, and the string becomes:

```
asdf & asdf&asdf
```

Now you again call

```
i = strcspn (input,keys)
```

And this returns `i = 4` because now it finds the first `&` in position 5. So when you insert spaces again the string becomes:

```
asdf  &  asdf&asdf
```

And so on. It keeps inserting more and more spaces around the first `&`, and the loop never ends until you overrun the buffer inside `appenda` and your program dies.

Instead, once you've inserted spaces, you need to tell `strcspn` to start looking for the next special character *past* the place where you found the previous one. This should work:

```
char keys[] = "<>&|";
int i = strcspn (input,keys);
while(i < strlen(input)){
    appenda(input, " " , i);
    i += 2;
    appenda(input, " " , i);
    i += strcspn (input + i,keys);
}
```

This "moves" the value of `i` such that when you call `strcspn(input + i, keys)`, the value `input + i` always refers to the next position that has not yet been looked at for special characters.

Comment: Of course... Can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much Tyler

Comment: By the way, this error was tricky to find because the message you got was so misleading. It's only because that weird implementation of `appenda` you copied uses a stack-based fixed-size buffer that you got this error instead of a stack overflow or an out-of-memory error. Either of those errors would have made me think about an infinite loop immediately.

Comment: BTW, the last code line should be just `i = strcspn (input + i,keys);`, not `+=`.

Comment: @KenY-N Incorrect. Tyler was right. It must be i += strcspn...

Comment: @user821863 Ah, yes indeed. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

What Tyler McHenry is exactly right. Though I'd instead suggest looping through character by character and copying it to a new array, since this prevents the need to move around all the characters continuously. Like so:

```
int len = 200;
char input[len+1];
char output[len*3+1];
int outPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  if (input[i] == 0) break; // end of string
  if (input[i] == '<' || input[i] == '>' || input[i] == '&' || input[i] == '|')
  {
    output[outPos++] = ' ';
    output[outPos++] = input[i];
    output[outPos++] = ' ';
  }
  else
    output[outPos++] = input[i];
}
output[outPos] = 0;
```