# Construct String in C

Tags: c, string

Here is the demo code I am using to construct string from char arrays, Is there any better way to construct String `*RV200#` `*FV200#`  ??

```
int main()
{    
char String4H1[10] = "*FV";
char String4H3[10] = "*RV";
char String4H2[10] = "#";

char data1[10];
char data2[10];

snprintf(data1,4, "%03d", 200); //Convert integer to string function
snprintf(data2,4, "%03d", 200); //Convert integer to string function

ConvertToString(String4H1,data1, 3);     //*FV200
ConvertToString(String4H3,data2, 3);     //*RV200

ConvertToString(String4H1,String4H2,6);   //*FV200#
ConvertToString(String4H3,String4H2,6);   //*RV200#

//Display String4H1 And String 4H3 

}


void ConvertToString(char subject[], const char insert[], int pos) 
{
char buf[100] = {};  
strncpy(buf, subject, pos);               // copy at most first pos characters
int len = strlen(buf);
strcpy(buf+len, insert);                 // copy all of insert[] at the end
len += strlen(insert);                  // increase the length by length of insert[]
strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos);          // copy the rest

strcpy(subject, buf);                 // copy it back to subject
                                 // deallocate buf[] here, if used malloc()
}
```

The number `200` is not known at the start of the program,  it is fetched from memory using the IDE function to get value from particular memory address.
like this :-

```
unsigned short BUF = GetWord(@FrontVIB@,0);    
unsigned short BUF1 = GetWord(@RearVIB@,0);

//BUF and BUF1 stores the value of address @FrontVIB@ and @RearVIB@ respectively

**structure** :-
unsigned short GetWord( @Address Alias@, Address Offset );
```

Comment: Why not just use `snprintf` for the whole string? Like `snprintf(data1, sizeof(data1), "%s%d%s", String4H1, 200, String4H2);`?

Comment: Why not use `snprintf()`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `"%s%d%s"` should be `"%s%03d%s"`

Comment: `snprintf(data1,sizeof(data1), "%s%03d#", String4H1, 200);`

Comment: `char String4H1[] = "*FV";` same for others

Comment: what if I need to create string like this `*VB200,100,050,025,020,010#`

Comment: `char buf[100] = {};` You're sure this is supposed to be C?

Comment: use `strcat`; compilers usually generate very good code for `strcpy(foo, "foo"); strcat(foo, "bar")`

Comment: You can use [strcat](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm).

Comment: @EOF [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459259/inserting-characters-into-a-string

Comment: @EmbeddedGeek: Did you read the comment under the answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: @LPs If you can answer this question with demo code for `*VB200,100,050,025,020,010#' using `strcat` . Please!

Comment: BTW it depens on what you want to achieve: are those numbers known at start of program? Are those number retrieve somehow through a stream? Elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @EmbeddedGeek, standard C does not permit empty initializers.  Some compilers accept it as an extension, but if you rely on that then you're not writing C, but rather some language derived from C and closely related to it.

Comment: @EOF Yes, but it worked perfect for me! Though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes it very closely related to C. But not exact C language. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: @LPs I am adding bit more info about my code.

Comment: @LPs I have updated the question, kindly check!

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple example. Probably I'll be down-voted :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool concatenateString(char **dest, size_t *size, char *stringToAdd)
{
    bool retVal = true;
    char *dest_old = *dest;

    *size += strlen(stringToAdd);

    if (*dest == NULL)
    {
        *size += 1; // to add null terminator of string
        *dest = calloc(1, size);
    }
    else
    {
        *dest = realloc(*dest, size);
    }

    if (dest == NULL)
    {
        free(dest_old);
        retVal = false;
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(*dest, stringToAdd);
    }

    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    char newString[32] = {0};
    int number;
    size_t size = 0;

    char *data1 = NULL;

    printf("Insert a string:");
    scanf(" %s", newString);
    if (concatenateString(&data1, &size, newString))
    {
        printf("Insert a number:");
        scanf(" %d", &number);
        sprintf(newString, "%03d", number);
        if (concatenateString(&data1, &size, newString) )
        {
            printf("Insert a string:");
            scanf(" %s", newString);
            if (concatenateString(&data1, &size, newString))
               printf("%s\n", data1);
        }
    }

    free(data1);
}
```

Without using dynamic allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool concatenateString(char *dest, size_t size_of_dest, char *stringToAdd)
{
    bool retVal = true;

    size_t new_size = strlen(dest) + strlen(stringToAdd);

    if (new_size < size_of_dest)    
    {
        strcat(dest, stringToAdd);
    } 
    else
    {
        retVal = false;
    }
    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    char result[128] = {0};
    char newString[32] = {0};
    int number;

    printf("Insert a string:");
    scanf(" %s", newString);
    printf("%s\n", newString);
    if (concatenateString(result, sizeof(result), newString))
    {
        printf("Insert a number:");
        scanf(" %d", &number);
        sprintf(newString, "%03d", number);
        if (concatenateString(result, sizeof(result), newString) )
        {
            printf("Insert a string:");
            scanf(" %s", newString);
            if (concatenateString(result, sizeof(result), newString))
               printf("%s\n", result);
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT

```
Insert a string: *RV
Insert a number: 200
Insert a string: #
```

OUTPUT

```
*RV200#
```

Comment: Considering the number of revisions you needed to make, perhaps the assertion that this is "simple" needs to be revised as well?

Comment: @EOF I'm a little bit crazy today and  I wrote the whole code through smartphone app. :D I was scared to lost the code. :) So better to edit than lost.

Comment: @EOF _simple_ is referred to the fact that the code uses scanf an take fixed 3 pars: string number string.

Comment: Your `concatenateString()` has a memory leak when `realloc()` fails, and I don't see how this is preferable to the `snprintf()` discussed in the comments to the question. Not my DV though.

Comment: It is bit of complicated! Not simple it seems.

Comment: @EOF Yes it is different from what discussed in comment section above. The `snprintf()` is more reliable and easy to use.

Comment: @EOF Well now I am in front of my PC. Good catch I edited. BTW OP asked for a sample code with strcat.

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues, I am only tackling `ConvertToString()`

---

Although some attempts made at coping with string buffer issues, too many holes exist in OP's code.  Consider the following.

```
void ConvertToString(char subject[], const char insert[], int pos) {
  char buf[100] = {};  
  strncpy(buf, subject, pos);               // copy at most first pos characters
  int len = strlen(buf);
  ...
```

What is the impact of `pos == 100`?
`strlen(buf)` may attempt to find the length of a character array with no null character --> UB.

What is the impact of `pos > 100`?
`strncpy()` attempts to write data outside the bonds of `buf`.

Pedantic: What is the impact of `pos < 0`?
`strncpy()` attempts to write data outside the bonds of `buf` as `pos` is converted into an excessive large unsigned number.

---

Concerning `strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos);`

What is the impact if `pos` exceeds `strlen(subject)`
UB as code attempts to read outside `subject`.

---

Re-write attempt.  The key elements: include the size available for the expanded `subject` is passed in and determine string lengths.  Then test for acceptability.  After all that, shift the end of `subject` to make room for `insert`.

```
void ConvertToString(char subject[], size_t subject_size, const char *insert,
    size_t pos) {

  size_t insert_length = strlen(insert);
  size_t subject_length = strlen(subject);
  // Insure pos does not exceed subject_length, 
  // this critical part missing in OP code 
  if (pos > subject_length) {
    pos = subject_length;
  }

  // Insure we have enough space
  size_t buf_size = subject_length + insert_length + 1;
  if (buf_size > subject_size) {
    Handle_Insufficent_subject_size();
    return;
  }
  // Move end portion of `subject` over to the right `insert_length` places.
  memmove(subject + pos + insert_length, subject + pos, subject_length - pos + 1);
  memcpy(subject + pos, insert, insert_length); // copy insert
}
```