# Convert a string into a specific date format

Tags: c, string, parsing, datetime

I have a 14 digit string with this data `20161909132409`, and I want to convert it to this format `YYYY-dd-mm hh:mm:ss` so it looks like: `2016-19-09 13:24:09`, but I don't know how to do it, can someone help me with the code please?

```
  char * strA = "00000000000000", * strB = "-", strC[50];
  int x = 4;
  strncpy(strC,strA,x);
  strC[x]= '\0';
  strcat(strC,strB);
  strcat(strC,strA+x);
  printf("%s\n",strC);
  return 0;
```

Can someone give an idea of how to add the deliminator with the strcat function?

Comment: Which language are you _actually_ using?  You have tagged both C and C++.

Comment: Use `std::string::substring()` and concatenation or `std::ostringstream`. Show some of your efforts at all please. We're not your _"Gimme teh codez plz"_ shopping mall here.

Comment: Alternatively if you have POSIX you can use strptime() to parse AND CHECK FOR ERRORS and then strftime() to reformat.

Comment: Please read [what you can ask here and how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Essentially you just want to insert characters into a string, and there's a few approaches to that. You know the length of the year is 4, everything else is 2; and you know the starting index of each field. I would use that knowledge and copy the data from the appropriate place in the source string to a new destination string, inserting the formatting characters as I went. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459259/inserting-characters-into-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is one of those scenarios, where a brute force approach of simply walking a pointer down the original datestring to insert the required date and time format separators, is just as easy, and efficient as anything else. The following code simply builds a buffer from your original string, inserting the the formatting in buffer at the appropriate separators and the required points as the data is copied from `data` to `buf` the index in `buf` is simply derived from the position of pointer `p`. At the end, after all separators have been inserted and all characters copied to `buf`, `buf` is `nul-terminated` and is no in a form to pass to your date functions., e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char data[] = "20161909132409",
        buf[32] = "", *p = buf;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (; data[i]; i++) {
        if (i < 4) *p++ = data[i];
        else if (i == 4) { *p++ = '-'; *p++ = data[i]; }
        else if (i < 6) *p++ = data[i];
        else if (i == 6) { *p++ = '-'; *p++ = data[i]; }
        else if (i < 8) *p++ = data[i];
        else if (i == 8) { *p++ = ' '; *p++ = data[i]; }
        else if (i < 10) *p++ = data[i];
        else if (i == 10) { *p++ = ':'; *p++ = data[i]; }
        else if (i < 12) *p++ = data[i];
        else if (i == 12) { *p++ = ':'; *p++ = data[i]; }
        else if (i < 14) *p++ = data[i];
    }
    *p = 0; /* nul-terminate */

    printf (" original  : '%s'\n formatted : '%s'\n", data, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fmrdatestr
original  : '20161909132409'
formatted : '2016-19-09 13:24:09'
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going down a needlessly complicated path using positions and string concatenation.  You'll end up with a load of code that's difficult to understand and with potentially hidden bugs.

It's a lot clearer to simply make a positional format string using a placeholder for the characters you want to insert.  This would do the trick:

```
char *format_date( char date[20], const char *input )
{
    const char format[20] = "XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX";
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        if( *input && format[i] == 'X' )
            date[i] = *input++;
        else
            date[i] = format[i];
    }
    return date;
}
```

And you can now re-use it:

```
int main(void)
{
    char date[20];

    /* simple example */
    format_date( date, "20161909132409" );
    printf( "%s\n", date );

    /* in-place example */
    printf( "%s\n", format_date( date, "20161909132409" ) );
    printf( "%s\n", format_date( date, "20161012131415" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice! much cleaner than my suggestion