# Insert hyphens after fifth character in C

Tags: c, linux

I have a char array, and I want to insert hyphens after every five characters. I have tried the following code but am looking for a better way to accomplish this task, what string function should I use, and how? Thanks. :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[]="356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab";
    char buf[50];

    sprintf(buf, "%.5s-%.5s-%.5s-%.5s-%.5s-%.5s-%.5s-%.5s",str, str+5,str+10,str+15,str+20,str+25,str+30,str+35,str+40);
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the information in the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459259/inserting-characters-into-a-string) and then use a loop to insert as many hyphens as you need rather than hard coding it like you're doing

Comment: turn on warnings.. you have one too many arguments in your `sprintf` line, both gcc and clang warned me... this is probably UB. But what output do you get? Looks like I'm getting what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459259/inserting-characters-into-a-string)

Comment: The following code worked for me   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++){
       if( (i % 5) == 0) {
         buf[5] = '-';
       }
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a helper function I whipped up for you.  It takes a string as a parameter along with the desired hyphens spacing and returns a new string with hyphens within it.  Notice it makes sure that there's no trailing hyphens at the end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* hyphenize(const char* str, int spacing)
{
    size_t len, newlen;
    char *ptr, *buf;

    if (spacing < 1)
    {
        return NULL; // error!
    }

    len = strlen(str);
    newlen = len + (len / spacing) + 1;
    buf = (char*)malloc(newlen);
    ptr = buf;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < len; x++)
    {
        *ptr++ = str[x];
        if ((x != 0) && (x != (len - 1)) && ((x + 1) % spacing == 0))
        {
            *ptr++ = '-';
        }
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab";
    char* p = hyphenize(str, 5);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice function thank you, can you please provide me another example without putting it in a function just putting the code in the Main()

Comment: @Djmc: that’s a nonsense request — or, a little more charitably, a sign of a novice.  You need code in functions, not in main.  You don’t write code that could be in a function as the code in `main()`.

Comment: Am asking for this cause I already have a function that generate a hardware based product keys and I want to incorporate this code into this function instead of jumping into another function. and off course am not coding this directly in the main function.so don't make assumptions.

Comment: SO is not for you to ask others do your assignments or homework for you. In providing an answer, my hope was that you would study it, learn from it, apply to your own understanding, and incorporate into your immediate problem. It's debatable if it makes sense to inline the code or have it componentized into a separate helper function. **But the ability to refactor and merge working code from one source and put into another is fundamental to all aspects of programming.** You need to learn how to do this through practice, trial and error, and ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and sorry for the misunderstanding, I code in C# so am new to C and still learning how to use pointers in functions, anyway I managed to finish my hobby project with your help and others here. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You know you want `(length - 1) / 5` hyphens. So for buf, you need storage for `buf[len + (len -1) / 5 + 1];` characters. Then simply loop over the characters in `str` and (skipping the case where `i = 0`) if `i % 5 == 0` write a hyphen to `buf` *in addition to* copying the character from `str`.

Putting it together, you can do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HYPHPOS 5

int main(void) {

    char str[] = "356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab";
    size_t len = strlen (str);
    char buf[len + (len -1)/ HYPHPOS + 1], *p = buf;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i && i % HYPHPOS == 0)
            *p++ = '-';
        *p++ = str[i];
    }
    *p = 0;

    printf ("str : %s\nbuf : %s\n", str, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also simply use `str[i]` as the loop test clause.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hyphenate
str : 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
buf : 356a1-92b79-13b04-c5457-4d18c-28d46-e6395-428ab
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `len + len / 5`, not `% 5`?

Comment: Yep, we all have our moments `:)`

Comment: `char buf[len + len / HYPHPOS]` appears 1 too small.  Consider `char str[] = "1";`  `buf[]` should be at least size 2.

Comment: Yes, we can add one, but I was counting on the fact that you don't insert a hyphen unless you have at least `6` chars. (but even then you still need the `+1`... hmmm. too much egg nog) Thanks!